# Selection vertices problem in edit mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

when I select a lot of vertices there are strange points - when I move the vertices, black or white dots appear and disappear, seemingly at random. What do I do?

Video that shows the problem can be found on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/cBvbkVkSdGw)

Comment: definitely looks like a bug with blender, could try reinstalling / a different version

Comment: Are you using an AMD video card?  Either way, make sure that your video card drivers are up to date.

Comment: No, I use Nvidia GTX 780